# libunistring u8_strlen() equals to strlen()?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

Just now I'm trying to use libunistring in my c program.
I've to process UTF-8 string, and for it I used u8_strlen() function from libunistring library.
Code example:

```
void print_length(uint8_t *msg) {
    printf("Default strlen: %d\n", strlen((char *)msg));
    printf("U8 strlen: %d\n", u8_strlen(msg));
}
```

Just imagine that we call `print_length()` with `msg = "привет"` (cyrillic, utf-8 encoding).
I've expected that `strlen()` should return 12 (6 letters * 2 bytes per letter), and
`u8_strlen()` should return 6 (just 6 letters).

But I recieved curious results:

```
Default strlen: 12
U8 strlen: 12
```

After this I'm tried to lookup u8_strlen realization, and found this code:

```
size_t
u8_strlen (const uint8_t *s)
{
    return strlen ((const char *) s);
}
```

I'm wondering, is it bug or it's correct answer? If it's correct, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the intended behavior.

[The libunistring manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html) says that:

> size_t u8_strlen (const uint8_t *s)
>
> Returns the number of units in s.

Also in the manual, it defines what this "unit" is:

> UTF-8 strings, through the type ‘uint8_t *’. The units are bytes (uint8_t).

I believe the reason they label the function `u8_strlen` even though it does nothing more than the standard `strlen` is that the library also has `u16_strlen` and `u32_strlen` for operation on UTF-16 and UTF-32 strings, respectively (which would count the number of 2-byte units until 0x0000, and 4-byte units until 0x00000000), and they included `u8_strlen` simply for completeness.

[GNU gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html) does however include `mbslen` which probably does what you want:

> mbslen function: Determine the number of multibyte characters in a string.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `u8_mbsnlen` function

> Function: size_t u8_mbsnlen (const uint8_t *s, size_t n)
>
> Counts and
> returns the number of Unicode characters in the n units from s.
>
> This function is similar to the gnulib function mbsnlen, except that
> it operates on Unicode strings.

([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html#index-u8_005fmbsnlen))

Unfortunately this needs you to pass in the length of the string in bytes as well.